# Python Tkinter creating new buttons but cant change old ones

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
def Nohinzu():
    global r
    global subject
    global grade
    grade = float(entry2.get())
    subject = entry1.get()
    entry1.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
    if grade <= 6 and grade >= 1:
        liste()
        update()
        durchschnitt()
        label = tk.Label(window, text="Average:", width=15).grid(row=3,column=0)
        label = tk.Label(window, text=du, width=15).grid(row=3,column=1)
        button1 = tk.Button(window, text=subjects[r], command=lambda: openNewWindow(subjects[r])).grid(row=r + 4,column=0)
        button2 = tk.Label(window, text=grades[r],)
        button2.grid(row=r + 4,column=1)
        r += 1
    else:
        Fehler(1)
```

Here is my code as you can see im creating a new button every time i use that command,but as there are 4 or 5 buttons every button should have his own Window, but idk how to do that.
For example:

Button: History          5
Button: Science          3
Button: PE               2
Button: History          3

What my buttons do is open a window where all Grades pop up, but if I would have clicked on PE History would still pop up and idk how to fix that.

I tried to play around with the r,but nothing really happend